Transform classes with Gradle API's TransformAction
According to the docs, one can register transforms for artifacts and apply tasks that require them, like the Minify example.
I'm looking to have an artifact transform at the .class level, i.e. not manipulating JARs but more generically: classes or class directories. A typical pipeline would then be source -> classes -> modifiedClasses -> jar
However the "classes" attribute does not exist for artifact types, e.g. this (or variants) does not work.
dependencies {
    registerTransform(Minify::class) {
        from.attribute(minified, false).attribute(artifactType, "classes")
        to.attribute(minified, true).attribute(artifactType, "classes")
    }
}

Can this be achieved with the Transform API? Or should it be a separate task with dependencies (but no caching capabilities)?
